# Ubuntu reports too little vram?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I was trying to see how much video ram I have, so I used `lspci` to find the device. There are two graphics cards in there, the integrated Intel one and an Nvidia one. The Nvidia one showed up as:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1fb9 (rev a1)
```

So then I used `lspci -v -s 01:00.0` to see more info about it. And it shows 256MB ram:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1fb9 (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
Subsystem: Lenovo Device 2297
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 180
    Memory at ea000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at a0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M] 
    Memory at b0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    I/O ports at 2000 [size=128]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at eb080000 [disabled] [size=512K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
```

However, I checked the configuration, and it should have 4GB of vram.
Windows (which is dual booted on the same laptop) also reports that the graphics card has 4GB of vram.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You interpreted the values in the wrong way. The three memory areas

```
Memory at ea000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
Memory at a0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M] 
Memory at b0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
```

are indicating the [MMIO memory spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_I/O) of your graphics card. And **not** the amount of video memory your graphics card(GC) has.

The MMIO memory spaces are used for the interaction between your GC memory and your main memory. For eaxmple, to transfer 128MB of data from your main memory to your GC memory, probably the second MMIO address at `a0000000` is used.

1. You call the video driver to move the memory window of the GPU memory to the target area of the GC memory.
2. You copy the data from your HOST memory(main memory) to the GPU memory at the given address in the MMIO memory space window.

The info of the amount of GPU memory is obviously not contained in the output of `lspci`.

Comment: Aha, then I was mislead online! Thanks for the explanation :D